# Winforms shadow border with CS_DROPSHADOW

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to achieve a shadow on a form with C# winforms 4.0.
I did some searching on this and found the following answer :

```
private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000; 
protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        // add the drop shadow flag for automatically drawing 
        // a drop shadow around the form 
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; 
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW; 
        return cp; 
    } 
}
```

However, using the above code, I can not see any shadow.
I opened a new clean winforms project in VS2010 and still cannot see a thing.
Need some guidance on what could be going wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your form a top-level form (i.e. not an MDI child)? Are drop shadows enabled on your system?

Comment: What windows version are you targeting?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's the only form I have in my app. (I try this on a new winforms project in VS2010). How can I check whether drop shadow is enabled? I'm targeting Windows7 64bit.

Comment: @TaW I'm targeting Windows7 64bit.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I tried to set TopLevel to both true & false. and it doesn't work on both cases. Further more, I checked the 'show shadow under menus' and it didn't helped as well :(

Comment: Check [System Properties -> Advanced -> Show shadow under windows] is checked or not. If you un-check it, shadow border won't show.